# Postgresql psql: FATAL: role "username" does not exist

Tags: postgresql, macos, psql

I have looked over all the questions posted previously and surprisingly NONE of them could resolve my problem. Can someone pls help me with this issue. I can post the outputs of the commands if someone can really help me. I am on MacOS BigSur 11.6

Here are the outputs of the common commands I tried from previous questions.

Command: `psql` or `psql -l`
Output: `psql: FATAL:  role "harshit" does not exist`

Command: `sudo psql`
Output: `psql: FATAL:  role "root" does not exist`

Command: `su - postgres`
Output: After entering the password , it says `su: Sorry`

Command: `ps ax | grep postgres`
Output:

```
47592   ??  S      0:00.12 /usr/local/opt/postgresql@9.6/bin/postgres -D /usr/local/var/postgresql@9.6
47599   ??  Ss     0:00.21 postgres: checkpointer process     
47600   ??  Ss     0:00.11 postgres: writer process     
47601   ??  Ss     0:00.08 postgres: wal writer process     
47602   ??  Ss     0:00.07 postgres: autovacuum launcher process     
47603   ??  Ss     0:00.38 postgres: stats collector process     
49153   ??  Ss     0:00.03 postgres: stark m3_india ::1(65520) idle  
49710 s002  S+     0:00.01 grep postgres
```

Command: `initdb /usr/local/var/postgresql@9.6` 
Output:

```
The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "harshit".
This user must also own the server process.

The database cluster will be initialized with locales
  COLLATE:  C
  CTYPE:    UTF-8
  MESSAGES: C
  MONETARY: C
  NUMERIC:  C
  TIME:     C
The default database encoding has accordingly been set to "UTF8".
initdb: could not find suitable text search configuration for locale "UTF-8"
The default text search configuration will be set to "simple".

Data page checksums are disabled.

initdb: directory "/usr/local/var/postgresql@9.6" exists but is not empty
If you want to create a new database system, either remove or empty
the directory "/usr/local/var/postgresql@9.6" or run initdb
with an argument other than "/usr/local/var/postgresql@9.6".
```

I thought after the above one, it shown user as "harshit" but still using this username, psql doesn't work. I can't remove the existing db as it has some useful information. Is there no way to access it now?

Edit:

Command: `sudo -u postgres psql`
Output:

```
sudo: unknown user: postgres
sudo: error initializing audit plugin sudoers_audit
```

Command: `ps aux | grep postgres`
Output:

```
harshit          52614   0.0  0.1  4490468  24964   ??  Ss    4:50PM   0:00.47 postgres: stark m3_india ::1(50059) idle  
harshit          52593   0.0  0.1  4489636  16320   ??  Ss    4:49PM   0:00.33 postgres: stark m3_india ::1(50052) idle  
harshit          52290   0.0  0.1  4488464   8688   ??  Ss    4:39PM   0:00.04 postgres: stark m3_india ::1(50004) idle  
harshit          51265   0.0  0.0  4342116   1140   ??  Ss    3:49PM   0:01.64 postgres: stats collector process     
harshit          51264   0.0  0.0  4487076   2504   ??  Ss    3:49PM   0:00.28 postgres: autovacuum launcher process     
harshit          51262   0.0  0.0  4487012   4896   ??  Ss    3:49PM   0:00.15 postgres: wal writer process     
harshit          51261   0.0  0.0  4487012   1812   ??  Ss    3:49PM   0:00.14 postgres: writer process     
harshit          51260   0.0  0.1  4487140  14444   ??  Ss    3:49PM   0:00.45 postgres: checkpointer process     
harshit          51217   0.0  0.1  4487304  14068   ??  S     3:49PM   0:00.30 /usr/local/opt/postgresql@9.6/bin/postgres -D /usr/local/var/postgresql@9.6
_postgres        49645   0.0  0.0  4334640   1136   ??  S     3:35PM   0:00.03 /usr/sbin/distnoted agent
harshit          53335   0.0  0.0  4268424    616 s002  R+    5:26PM   0:00.00 grep postgres
```

Command: `whoami`
Output: `harshit`

Command: `psql -U postgres`
Output: `psql: FATAL:  role "postgres" does not exist`

Command: `psql -U stark`
Output: `psql: FATAL:  database "stark" does not exist`

Edit: Trying to create users

Command: `sudo -u postgres createuser harshit -s with password "123"` or `sudo -u postgres psql -c "ALTER ROLE harshit WITH PASSWORD '123';"` or `sudo -u postgres createuser -s -i -d -r -l -w harshit` or `sudo -u postgres -i`
Output:

```
sudo: unknown user: postgres
sudo: error initializing audit plugin sudoers_audit
```

Comment: and what about : sudo -u postgres psql ?

Comment: @FatFreddy I've added that output as well. Appreciate your help in resolving it

Comment: Run ps aux | grep postgres to find out which user is running the postgres process. Then log in as that user and execute psql.

Comment: @MarcinJ I added that output as well. U can see I am logged in with the same user. Is there something else I need to do.

Comment: Couple things you can try: create the postgres user on your machine and then impersonate and run psql. Or you can check postgresql.conf and pg_hba.conf (most likely in /usr/local/var/postgresql@9.6 or somewhere within) to see if it allows METHOD = md5 connections, then you'd need to know the username and password to log in with.

Comment: If you have never been able to get into it, how did the useful info get there?

Comment: What about `psql -U postgres`?

Comment: Or, based on your ps output, `psql -U stark`, since that user clearly exists?

Comment: @jjanes I was able to login easily earlier. But then due to some reason I had to change my username from `stark` to `harshit`. since then it stopped working.

Comment: @jjanes I added the output of both the commands u suggested but no luck. Also if we just leave apart logging in, why am I not able to create a new user. Added the output for that as well

Comment: @MarcinJ I checked the files u mentioned. Cudn't find anything related to md5 there

Comment: Note the error changed from role to database, so then 'stark' the role does exist.  Now guess what databases might exist, or use 'm3_india'.  So `psql -U stark m3_india`

Comment: @jjanes hi. Thanks very much. This solved my problem. I somehow forgot to reply. U can make it an answer and I'll be more than happy to accept it.